# What's the difference between php@7.1 and php71 [Homebrew on macOS]

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I ran `brew update && brew upgrade` this morning and this warning came out:

```
> ==> Renamed Formulae
php71 ✔ -> php@7.1
==> Deleted Formulae
homebrew/php/php71-gmp        homebrew/php/php71-mcrypt     homebrew/php/php71-pcntl      homebrew/php/php71-pdo-pgsql  homebrew/php/php71-snmp
homebrew/php/php71-intl       homebrew/php/php71-opcache    homebrew/php/php71-pdo-dblib  homebrew/php/php71-pspell     homebrew/php/php71-tidy
==> Processing php71 formula rename to php@7.1
==> Unlinking php71
==> Moving php71 versions to /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1
==> Relinking php@7.1
Warning: php@7.1 is outdated!
To avoid broken installations, as soon as possible please run:
  brew upgrade
Or, if you're OK with a less reliable fix:
  brew upgrade php@7.1
```

what does that `@` represent?

Comment: That might just be the version separator.

Comment: Probably represents `at version`? So PHP at version 7.1

Comment: The `@` is often used to tell the version number. In this case, `php` is the program, `7.1` is the version. I'm not sure to understand the question though. There might be no differences, just a different path for the same program. Please clarify if I'm wrong.

Comment: The title of your question is about to give me a stroke, what is `php7.1.7.15`?

Comment: It's the new notation of versions Homebrew adopted some time ago. In the past there were `php70`, `php71`, `php72` and other similar packages for various versions of PHP. Now the current version (`7.2`) is named `php` (no version indication) and the others are `php@7.0`, `php@7.1` and so on (the version follows the `@` sign).

Comment: I've the same trouble...
Now how is it possible to install php71-intl, php71-mcrypt and php71-tidy?

Comment: @Ephraim lots of these libraries are packaged into php@7.1 now.  Just run `php -i` to check, you'll see for example that intl and mcrypt are ready to go without the need to install php71-mcrypt as was done before.

Comment: @axiac is right. i've installed php72 and it's named php now. the others are having the @ symbol. i guess we gonna get used to this new notation.
For those of you who are confused or got their packages messed up, i just uninstalled Homebrew and installed everything clean again....took some minutes but everything is working fine now.

Comment: This article describes this "issue" https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

Answer (score 2):

As said in some comments, the program in itself is the same. It's still PHP, and still version 7.1.

But if you look at the [homebrew/core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/a0b705d836195c4116721e568fcb5a33835bcb5f) and [homebrew/php](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/commit/ab5fffa7cf3b7dca77f2ffa6f6104fc09fd72221) repositories, you will see that PHP 7.1 has been migrated from homebrew/php to homebrew/core, and it is only the naming that changes.

In homebrew/php it was named php71, and in homebrew/core it's named php@7.1 to separate program and version.

Comment: Whose genius idea was this change?!
I now can't do `brew link php71` anymore, without forcing it, and when I force I get the same error as with `brew link php`. Some symlink that can't be set, so I had to add `--overwrite`.
After having done so, now my php version is not configured properly anymore and throws different errors in different situations (composer, symfony etc)
My whole php setup is jammed by this change! What can I do?

Comment: I've not updated my PHP yet, I'm using PHP 7.2 but I guess I'll have the same problem. I guess all your `php71` have been moved to `php@7.1`, so what would you to more? Now use only `php@7.1` when you want to do something.

Comment: @AndreasSpaeth This change has been announced 3 months ago. It was a hell to maintain homebrew/php outside of homebrew/core and was a bad experience to users as well. If you think there’s an issue, please report it and/or make a pull-request on Homebrew. Complaining never solves anything.

Comment: There seems to be issues changing between 5.6 and 7 - when you try swap it just says "this version is already linked"

Comment: @bfontaine Where has it been announced? How do I handle the change?
For me, *the change* resulted in a bad user experience, because I did not know of it.
Sure, complaining never solves anything, but in fact I described my problem and asked what I could do about it. (sorry if I could not completely hide my displeasure about a minor unrelated package installation rendering my whole setup useless)
Destructive criticism (opposed to constructive) never solves anything, either ;)
You seem to be an advanced user, so why don't you provide information *helpful* to the problem in a separate answer?

Comment: @AndreasSpaeth See the blog post for Homebrew 1.5.0: https://brew.sh/2018/01/19/homebrew-1.5.0/. There’s nothing I can add that wasn’t mentioned in the comments; I was just reacting to your "Whose genius idea was this change?!". That genius is an OSS maintainer who work for free on their free time on something you don’t pay a single dollar to use. You can criticize without insulting the people you rely on. If you think there’s an issue, please contribute to the project by opening an issue or a PR. (disclaimer: I’m a former maintainer so I know what it’s like to work on such a big OSS project).

Comment: @bfontaine thanks for the reference! Seems like learning how to stay up-to-date on 100s of dependencies I have to use in daily business is one of the skills I have yet to learn. It also seems like you misinterpreted my intentions. I never intended to insult anyone, nor did I imho. Sorry if my wording offended you.